# How do i output link under each catergory with each drop down menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery

`

```js
$(function(){
 $('.addLink').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var content = $('.categorySelect');
  var url = $("#userInput").val();
  var link = "<a href='" + url + "'>" + "<br />" + url + "</a>";
  $(link).appendTo('.sports');
 });
});
```

```html
 Choose Category:
        <select class='categorySelect'>
        <option value="Sports" id="a">Sports</option>
        <option value="World" id="b">World</option>
        <option value="Movies" id="c">Movies</option>
        </select><br />

       <input type='text' id='userInput' placeholder='Enter Link Here' />
       <input type='button'  value='Add' class='addLink'/>
       
    <div class='sports'>
    Sports:
   </div>
    <div class='world'><br />
    World:
      </div>
     <div class='movies'><br />
    Movies:
      </div>
      </div>
```

`heres what i have now. when the user chooses a catergory from the dropdown menu their typed in link will show under that caterory(div class). i cant seem to figure this out.

Comment: this is what i want the outcome to be: when the user chooses a catergory from the dropdown menu their typed in link will show under that caterory(div class). i cant seem to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.addLink').click(function () {
    var content = $('.categorySelect').val().toLowerCase();
    var url = $("#userInput").val();
    var link = "<a href='" + url + "'>" + "<br />" + url + "</a>";
    $(link).appendTo('.'+content);
});
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b7yj2axs/)

First, you don't need `event.preventDefault()` because the input field doesn't have a default action that needs to be suppressed (cf. the `a` tag, which does).

Next, you need to grab the value of the SELECT *and convert to lowercase*, since that is the case of the class.

To append to the correct class, you concat the `.` class indicator to the name of the class extracted from the SELECT option value.

---

If you wanted to make the action automatic upon selection of a category, then change this:

```
$('.addLink').click(function () {
```

to this:

```
$('.categorySelect').change(function () {
```

[Revised jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7yj2axs/1/)

Note how we can use `$(this)` to refer to the control that triggered the event. By using `$(this)`, we can chain jQuery methods, e.g.

```
var content = $(this).val();
```

If all we want is the value, we can use pure javascript as it is a bit faster:

```
var content = this.value;
```

*Since `.toLowerCase()` is pure javascript, we can still go with `this.value`*

```
var content = this.value.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Glad to help. Please use checkmark to select a correct answer when you are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

I have wrote some working code for you, with comments included on Fiddle:

```
$(function(){
    $('.addLink').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        /* 
        Select the value of the dropdown (lowercase the values because your 
        HTML classes are written lowercase) and the values of your dropdown are not.
        */
        var content = $('.categorySelect').val().toLowerCase();
        var url = $("#userInput").val().toLowerCase();

        var link = "<a href='" + url + "'>" + "<br />" + url + "</a>";

        //Save check if the user has filled in a URL.        
        if(url !== '')
          //append URL link to the selected value of the dropdown.
          $(link).appendTo('.'+content);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9fc8zb4b/

Comment: Yup, you got it also. Good job. +1